# Modify tomcat server properties from running web application

Tags: tomcat, osgi

I have an OSGI based application running inside Tomcat container. This is working fine, however there is a specific ask for which i could not get any good resource.

I want to be able to modify the Tomcat properties in the run time and i am not sure how to even approach the same. Current approach I am trying is to change the server.xml file restart the tomcat. However it is not a hot deployment and would bring down the server.

Any better approach if some one can point to or suggest here will be really helpful.

Let me know if further information is needed. I don't know much, since i could not find great resources to get started.

**UPDATE:** SSL certificate is added to tomcat and path defined in server.xml. In real time, there is a situation where that certificate needs to be changed, either in the same location or any other. In anyways, is it possible i can achieve the same same without restarting the server itself?

Br,

AJ

Comment: In order to give you a proper answer, can you please specify what are you trying to modify in the server.xml?

Comment: What do you really want to do?

Comment: sure, ryt away, will update the question...

Comment: Hi, sorry for late update, i have updated the question. thanks for looking into this.

Comment: any suggestions @Liron

Answer (score 0):

In order to take the changes into affect, a restart to the tomcat server is needed - therefor you will get downtime.

My suggestion is to put a reverse proxy in front of the tomcat server ([Nginx](http://nginx.org/) for example) and do the SSL offloading there.
It will be much easier to change the configuration there and reload the settings with out restarting your webapp.

Hope it will help,

Liron

Comment: Hi Liron, thanks for the suggestion, let me go through this a bit and then will update...

Comment: Liron, i did not get exactly how this can help me in not restarting the Nginx server, can you suggest something here?

Comment: You will still need to [reload](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) the nginx server but that you can do from your own JAVA app without taking your taking down.
Also reloading configuration on Nginx is much faster.
Nginx also support multiple SSL certificates which mean you can have backward compatibility for old configs as well.